# Random NoThumb For Blogger

Tags: thumbnails, blogger

Is there any way I can make more than one default thumbnail in blogger? I would like to chose maybe three images to show at random when there is no post image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.random()` with an array, for example

```js
let thumbnails = ["thumb-1.png","thumb-2.png","thumb-3.png"];

// inside loop or whatever
if(/*check if post has thumbnail*/){
    // use post thumbnail
    // ...
} else { // else if no thumbnail use fallback
    let noThumb = thumbnails[Math.floor(Math.random()*thumbnails.length)]
    console.log(noThumb) // random thumbnail
}
```